# Some children positions are off, both when animating and rendering (but not when paused at any frame)

Tags: parent, drivers

I constructed a car where the tires are parented to the wheels and the weels are parented to the axes. These axes rotate with a simple driver on the world x location of the tires.
When moving the playhead 1 frame at the time, the positions are correct, but when playing the animation the tires lag behind (also when playing the animation backwards: the tires are sometimes catching up with their parents too slow)

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I realized the problem.
To have a more correct rotation of the weels when steering left or right, I set the driver to the x position of the tire,
creating a driver to a property of a child (of a child) caused the problem.
Instead I created an empty that is parented to the main steering object with an offset to the center of the wheel, resulting in a more correct rotation and preventing these delays